# What is the meaning of `printf("%p")` without arguments

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I of course know it used to output pointer with arguments.

I read book *Writing Secure Code* by Michael Howard and David LeBlanc.

One program in book demonstrates how stack overflow works by `strcpy()`

Note `printf()` without arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(const char* input)
{
    char buf[10];

    //What? No extra arguments supplied to printf?
    //It's a cheap trick to view the stack 8-)
    //We'll see this trick again when we look at format strings.
    printf("My stack looks like:\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n% p\n\n");

    //Pass the user input straight to secure code public enemy #1.
    strcpy(buf, input);
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    printf("Now the stack looks like:\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n\n");
}

void bar(void)
{
    printf("Augh! I've been hacked!\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Blatant cheating to make life easier on myself
    printf("Address of foo = %p\n", foo);
    printf("Address of bar = %p\n", bar);
    if (argc != 2) 
    {
        printf("Please supply a string as an argument!\n");
        return -1;
        } 
    foo(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
C:\Secureco2\Chapter05>StackOverrun.exe Hello
Address of foo = 00401000
Address of bar = 00401045
My stack looks like:
00000000
00000000
7FFDF000
0012FF80 
0040108A <-- return address
00410EDE

Hello
Now the stack looks like:
6C6C6548 <-- 'l','l','e','h'
0000006F <-- 0, 0, 0, 'o'
7FFDF000
0012FF80
0040108A
00410EDE
```

What is the meaning of `printf("%p")` inside code? Why it can print the content of stack?

Comment: Did you consider reading your platforms manual about the `printf` function and its formatting specifiers?

Comment: This is undefined behaviour.  Your compiler/libc decides what to do.

Comment: Will all due respect, I can see my previous comment "RTFM with a link to `printf()` man page" has been deleted. Why's so? How was that inappropriate?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I of course know %p used to output pointer. I want to know why %p can output the content of stack WITHOUT arguments.

Answer (score 11):

In general, `%p` is a [format specifier to print the pointer](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) (address value), the argument expected is a pointer to `void` type.

That said, in your code,

```
 printf("My stack looks like:\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n% p\n\n");
```

is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
As per the `printf()` description in the standard, if there are insufficient arguments for supplied format, it's UB.

To quote the standard, `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1

> [...] If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined. .[...]

The code snippet has zero guarantee to produce any valid output.

Answer (score 7):

The behaviour of `printf("Now the stack looks like:\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n\n");` is *undefined* since your argument list does not match the input string.

The authors are conjecting that this particular misuse of `printf` will inject variables from the current stack, and output their addresses. Sometimes they might be correct. Other times the compiler might eat your cat.

Comment: The goal of author here is to demo how to compromise system by `strcpy()` instead of `printf()`. Author use `printf` without arguments to output the content of stack to show how tampering return address by misuse of `strcpy`.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, this is undefined behaviour.

But what you see seems to be an admittedly naive but "natural" thing.  In most C implementation based on the call stack, function input arguments are pushed onto the stack by the caller, and popped[1] off the stack by the callee.  In this particular case, the callee (`printf`) seems to blindly pop successive pointer-sized elements, based on how many `%p` formatting directives there are in the formatting string, without any form of checking.  So instead of popping off the (absent) input arguments, it traverses the stack and "sees" what it's not supposed to see.  But this is not always the case for other implementations.

[1] By "popping off" I don't mean destructively removing them from the stack;  don't take it literally ;)  Most likely what happens under-the-hood is that the input arguments are referenced by an offset from a pointer.  But here apparently there's no constraint on how far this offset can get.

Comment: Please note that ALL the calls to C functions with variable arguments are done using the "C call convention", which places all the variable arguments into the stack, always. The callee does not have any information about how many parameters have passed, so it has to rely on other ways to figure it out (in this case, the formatting string), and it will search for them in the stack, as the call convention states.

Comment: @LoPiTaL, The compiler has all the information for the callee so this kind of check can happen at compile time.  With `gcc`, the `-Wformat` flag enables checking formatting string against the data arguments.

Comment: Nope, '-Wformat' enables this checking ONLY in the particular case of printf family functions, since they are well known and standard, not in any other case. Also, it has this information at the calling time, not inside the callee, what if the function is inside some library and has been exported? At that time, the compiler does not know how it will be called. Afterwards, when using this library, the compiler may not have the source code, so it does not know how it should be used.

Answer (score 4):

It means it will print output in a specific format. In the case of parameter "%p" it will be printed in the memory address format for your system (8 digits, hexadecimal).